# Нужна ли запятая перед КАК? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед КАК в этом предложении?

*Все люди мне улыбаются **как** узрят меня перед собой.*

Comment: Да, потому что это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным времени "как узрят меня перед собой". От основной части можно задать смысловой вопрос "когда?".

Comment: @nomnoms запятая-то нужна, а вот доказать, что это придаточное (да еще ***времени***) будет посложнее. Здесь "как" в значении "если", а это если и придаточное, то придаточное условия.

Answer (score 1):

**Все люди мне улыбаются, как узрят меня перед собой.**

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
[КАК](http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)
**2. союз**
**4.** Употр. при присоединении придаточных предложений времени, указывая на:
1) одновременность действия, соответствуя по знач. союзам: **когда, в то время когда**;
2) повторяемость действия, соответствуя по значению сл.: **всякий раз, когда**;
3) последовательность действия.
**6.** *разг.* Употр. при присоединении условных придаточных предложений; 
соответствует по знач. союзам: **в том случае, когда; если.**

В сложноподчиненном предложении перед союзом «как» необходима запятая. Вид придаточного предложения (времени или условия), думаю, можно определить по контексту.

Второе местоимение (мне — меня) в предложении представляется лишним.
Все люди мне улыбаются, как узрят (= увидят) перед собой.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна.

Здесь `как` употребляется в значении `когда`. Можно даже заменить. А перед `когда` всегда ставиться запятая.